# Select specific month and year records mysql from timestamp column

Tags: mysql

what im trying to do is select and count the diagnosis of patient from specific month and year. i already select and count the diagnosis what my problem is how to select this in specific month and year.

my query
     `SELECT diagnosis, count(diagnosis) as total from patient_records where 
     deleted_at is null group by diagnosis`

table structure
patient_records

```
#   Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    

1   idPrimary   int(10)     UNSIGNED    No

2   diagnosis   varchar(191)    utf8_unicode_ci     

3   remarks text    utf8_unicode_ci     Yes NULL             

4   created_at  timestamp           Yes NULL             

5   updated_at  timestamp           Yes NULL             

6   deleted_at  timestamp           Yes NULL             

7   patient_id  int(10)     UNSIGNED    Yes NULL
```

pls help me im a beginner
the query in my mind is like this

```
 SELECT diagnosis, count(diagnosis) as total from patient_records where 
 deleted_at is null and updated_at = month(5)&year(2019) group by 
 diagnosis
```

Comment: Look into MySQL Date/Time Functions..https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/date-and-time-functions.php   Specifically, look at the Month() and Year() functions

Comment: Note that functions cannot use indexes , so a range query is preferable

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  diagnosis, 
  count(diagnosis) as total,
  DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m') As month, 
  YEAR(created_at) as Year 
from patient_records 
where deleted_at is null 
group by diagnosis
```